# Prevent nullable parameter in stored procedure with LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq, stored-procedures

I want to define stored procedure parameters which do not allow null arguments.

[alt text http://www.pixelshack.us/images/xg3mr2xw0q13z22nal.jpg](http://www.pixelshack.us/images/xg3mr2xw0q13z22nal.jpg)

That `@MailItemId int OUTPUT` will be not nullable because when I import the stored procedure into the LINQ to SQL designer it says @MailIetmid is `ref int? mailItemId`.

[alt text http://www.pixelshack.us/images/er80hukg27lreiy9b83y.jpg](http://www.pixelshack.us/images/er80hukg27lreiy9b83y.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: Does specifying a default value help? (@MailItemID int = 0 OUTPUT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing else, you can just modify the auto-generated code (in designer.cs) to not accept a nullable integer. If the parameter ever does end up being null, it will probably cause a weird exception down in the LINQ to SQL code, but that's not a huge deal.

Comment: It seems pretty useful to me. So I'll try it right away. I'll tell you whether it will work or not :) But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this. Types in SQL Server can always be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function instead that returns an INT.

On the other hand, it is possible from SQL point of view that a NULL can be returned from function. I don't know how code generator will generate function for that. If it still returns a nullable int, I don't think it could be possible.

Answer (score -2):

You can specify a default value instead:

```
@MailItemId int OUTPUT = 0
```

or something like that

Comment: That doesn't prevent the type being nullable, it just defines a default value which is not null. The two things are orthogonal.