# What would cause linq to sql to think that a parameter is nullable?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that declares a input parameter

```
@BatchNumber uniqueidentifier
```

This field in the table is set to not allow nullables.

When I drag in the stored procedure and it hooks everything up it says the parameter is nullable.

I don't understand why. Is this normal for it to think that the parameters are nullable?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183460/prevent-nullable-parameter-in-stored-procedure-with-linq

Comment: So a sql type can always be null? I don't like that guys accepted answer as you should not change stuff in the auto-generated code as if it ever gets recreated then it gets overridden.

Comment: @chobo2 - Rather than changing it in the generated code, you might be able to change it in the .dbml file by hand editing it.

Comment: @Eric: The .dbml file is still refreshed whenever you generate new entities from the database.

Comment: Ya so I am looking for a different solution then trying to change .dbml file by hand. If you can change it through the properties window that is fine as I do not believe that gets overrideen but I could be mistaken. Or is what I am trying to do even possible like if this is a sql thing then maybe linq to sql is working as advertised.

Comment: @BlueRaja - that's only true if you're using a generator (such as SQLMetal) to make a fresh dbml file.  If you're using the designer, your changes to existing mappings stay intact when you add new mappings.

Comment: @David: Unfortunately, that's not true.  Every time I refresh my design from the DB, I need to re-edit my DBML file because Entity Framework incorrectly removes mappings between views and changes primary keys (because views cannot actually have primary/foreign keys, so it tries to infer them... incorrectly).

Comment: EF and LinqToSql are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All variables in Sql are nullable.  There is no way to make a non-nullable variable in sql.

```
 --yup, it's nullable.  even starts initialized to null.
DECLARE @MyVar int
```

If you change the parameter type in the designer, that should be fine.

The mapping code can have a non-nullable and hand it to the database and the database will call it a nullable and there is no problem.  This happens with every non-nullable in your queries already... such as non-nullable integer IDs in Where clauses.

If you can't set the type as desired in the designer.. here's what to do.  Take the generated code for the method and copy it out of the designer.cs file into a new partial class definition.  Set the type by hand in the attributes of the method.  Remove the stored proc from the designer (at this point, the stored proc is a manual addition).  We had to use this style of fix to allow OUTPUT parameters to work.

Comment: Ah so make a partial class with it overriding this nullable type. That way even if the DBML is recreated it won't effect it.